# How do I use sed to replace a single '?

Tags: sed

I need to replace '30 by `30 in a bunch of files. The following does not work:

```
grep -Rl "'30"  /myDir | xargs  sed -i "s/'30/`30/g"
```

How do I fix it?

I am on a Fedora 26 machine.

Comment: What output are you trying to achieve? You might try ``tr "'" '`'`` instead of sed

Comment: I need to replace '30 by `30 in a bunch of tex files.

Comment: That's the kind of detail that needs to be specified in the question.

Comment: Ok, but actually, that line just does not produce an output. That was the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a backslash before the backtick:

```
grep -Rl "'30" /myDir | xargs  sed  "s/'30/\`30/g"
```

Comment: the OP had `sed -i`...

Answer (score 0):

```
find /myDir -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -q \'30 {} \; -exec sed -i -e y/\'/\`/ {} +
```

Here you allow `find` to filter the files, in the directory `/myDir`, carrying the string ,`'30`, and pass only those, in a bunch, to `sed, which'll do an in-place editing`-i` on them.